# Python: GUI - plotting, reading from pixels in real-time GUI

Tags: python, numpy, user-interface, matplotlib, arduino

I've got a project in the works. I'm a rookie, roommate is a software engineer and suggested I used python for this project. My questions are listed below. first, here is an overview of what I am attempting to accomplish.

***project overview:***

> An array of addressable RGB led matrices, say, 50 leds x 50 leds (250
>   leds).   The led matrix is connected to and ran by an arduino which
>   will receive the matrix's pattern information from a decentralized
>   program. (We'll worry about the arduino's function later)
>
> The purpose of the program is to generate and send pattern information
>   for each addressable LED to the arduino.
>
> The program will host a GUI in order to alter and visualize the
>   outgoing or current matrix colormap and pattern in real-time (ie. turn on/off
>   strobe effect, turn on/off fade effect). The program will then read
>   from the gui to generate and translate RGB values to send to the
>   arduino.

Here is where I am at, and I need guidance. As of now, I am focusing on getting the GUI to work properly before moving on to the next parts of this project.

I'm using matplotlib in hopes that I can create a plot of 50x50 squares (or pixels) and retain control over each individuals point's value and struggling greatly. Ideally, I would be able to draw to the plot 30 times a second, or however many times so that it would appear to be updating in "real-time".

Here is some sample code so you can get a better understanding of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import random

fig = plt.figure()
matrix = random((50,50))
plt.imshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.spectral)


def update(data):
    print("IN UPDATE LOOP")
    matrix = random((50,50))
    return matrix

def data_gen():
    print("IN DATA_GEN LOOP")
    while True: yield np.random.rand(10)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=1000)
plt.imshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.spectral)
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```

[Photo of matrix with random values assigned to each square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y037n.png)

Grid won't update, not sure why...

Why is my grid not updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the first two questions as they are not really on topic here, the problem with the code is that you never actually update the image. This should be done in the animating function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import random

fig = plt.figure()
matrix = random((50,50))
im = plt.imshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.Spectral)

def update(data):
    im.set_array(data)

def data_gen():
    while True: 
        yield random((50,50))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is exactly what I needed... Basically answers all of my questions.